# how do you pass down an object containing props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

after getting all mixed up with state, i am now trying to restructure my app in a way that might be more reflective of best practices (not sure if this is the way, advice is welcome.)

so, i have my main page, which holds 3 states: viewer,buyside,sellside

there are also three different components, one for each of those states.

i want to be able to pass the props down from the main page, through those components, to their children (i've read this is the best approach??)

**main page:**

```
  //we have 3 states for the website: viewer,buyside customer, sellside customer
  const [visitorType, setVisitorType] = useState('viewer');
  
  if (visitorType == 'viewer') {
    return(
      <div>
        <Viewer visitortype='viewer' setvisitor={()=>setVisitorType()}/>
      </div>
    )}
  else if (visitorType =='buyside') {
    return(
      <div>
        <Buyside visitortype='buyside' setvisitor={()=>setVisitorType()}/>
      </div>
    )}
  else if (visitorType =='sellside') {
    return(
      <div>
        <Sellside visitortype='sellside' setvisitor={()=>setVisitorType()}/>
      </div>
    )}
  };
```

what is the best way to pass down the main page props, so that i can bring them down to any grandchildren, along with the child props?

**the viewer component -UPDATED-:**

```
const MainView = (props) => {
    return(
        <>
            <Navbar mainprops={{props}}/>
        </>
    )
};

export default MainView
```

i was previously just passing them individually, but realized it might be better to do so as one object...

**UPDATE: point taken on the syntax, but i'm wondering how i can best pass the objects**

**nav component (grandchild)**

```
const Navbar = (props) => {
  const {mainprops} = props.mainprops;

  if (mainprops.visitortype == 'viewer') {
    return(
      <>
      <h1>viewer navbar</h1>
      </>
    )}
  else if (mainprops.visitortype =='buyside') {
    return(
      <>
      <h1>buyside navbar</h1>
      </>
    )}
  else if (mainprops.visitortype =='sellside') {
    return(
      <>
      <h1>sellside navbar</h1>
      </>
    )}
  };

export default Navbar;
```

**UPDATE 2 - this works, but not sure if it is the correct way, are these still considered object literals??**

viewer component:

```
const MainView = (props) => {
    const mainprops = {...props}
    return(
        <>
            <Navbar mainprops={mainprops}/>
        </>
    )
};

export default MainView
```

navbar component

```
const Navbar = (props) => {
  const mainprops = {...props.mainprops};

  if (mainprops.visitortype == 'viewer') {
    return(
      <>
      <h1>viewer navbar</h1>
      </>
    )}
  else if (mainprops.visitortype =='buyside') {
    return(
      <>
      <h1>buyside navbar</h1>
      </>
    )}
  else if (mainprops.visitortype =='sellside') {
    return(
      <>
      <h1>sellside navbar</h1>
      </>
    )}
  };

export default Navbar;
```

if this is correct, then is this what @amir meant?

Comment: what if you destruct the object to `({ visitortype, setvisitor })` ?

Answer (score 1):

First there are certain rules for passing props:

1. You never ever pass literal object as props since it will not be the same every re-render and will cause the child component to re-render too (without any new info)
2. You don't need to do that

```
  <Viewer visitortype='viewer' setvisitor={()=>setVisitorType()}/>
```

You can:

```
  <Viewer visitortype='viewer' setvisitor={setVisitorType}/>
```

since it comes from `useState` react make sure the `setVisitorType` keeps the same reference

And now for you error, you almost correct you just did a js syntax error
you should write it like this:

```
const MainView = (props) => {
    return(
        <>
            <Navbar mainobj={{
                visitortype:props.visitortype,
                setvisitor:props.setvisitor
            }}
            />
        </>
    )
};

export default MainView
```

But again you never send literal object as props
I would keep it inside a ref or state (depend if the visitor state will be change)

Comment: thanks for taking the time!  so, let's say i want to pass all the props from the main page, down to the viewer component, down to the nav component...and i want the nav component to get the props from both the parent and grandparent...if im not supposed to do it with literal objects, then how do i bunch them together...i will update the question to show

Comment: You don't have to stack them together as an object you are just passing to string 
it it were 5+ i would suggest you to use object...
if you really want to use object save them in ref and then send the ref object down

Comment: hmm, but right now i only have two props - i might have twent later!

Comment: see my updated answer- another soultion is to use context API to prevent props drilling and it seems that the visitor state will be used in many level because it is an important state that controls the UI

Comment: its the last part im a bit slow on...i plan to have the state changed, depending on if someone logins thru the navbar lets say..and depending on the state, the navbar will look differently...could you expand on why a literal object shouldnt be sent as a prop?

Comment: This is how react checks the difference between state and props when a compoent rendered, 
{name:"avnav99} !== {name:"avnav99"}

even it has same properties  they are not same objects
and this will cause you navBar to rerender, you may not see any issue but on mobile or weak PC you might

Comment: oooh i see! so, am i supposed to destructor every time i go down a level??

Comment: ive added my updated script to the answer, is this what you meant?